# How to truncate double variables in CSV files python

Tags: python, csv, double, truncate

I have a CSV file that has columns like longitude and latitude. It looks like:

longitude      latitude

-99.148144  19.503343

-99.148311  19.503349

-99.148242  19.503267

-99.138863  19.474553

-99.148239  19.503267

However, I want to make a new CSV file (I know how to do this), but in this new CSV file I just want 3 digits after point, somthing like:

longitude      latitude

-99.148  19.503

-99.148  19.503

-99.148  19.503

-99.138  19.474

-99.148  19.503

PS: I am using native libraries of python and pandas to manage CSV files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formatted printing when you write the CSV file.  For example:

```
with open("output.csv", 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write("Datapoint: %.3f\n" % (3.14159))
```

It works very similarly to printf in C/C++.

This works, but is considered a deprecated style of formatting.  You could also use the more up-to-date *.format* approach:

```
with open("output.csv", 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write("Datapoint: {:.3f}\n".format(3.14159))
```

Here's a list of other formatting flags and more examples of both approaches if you need something more complicated:
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php

Comment: The page you linked mention it. The % notation is considered deprecated and should use the .format method instead

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Firstly I converted my coordinates into a double variables (because coordinates were string variables) and then I used the .format method to be able to truncate the coordinates. Thanks.